# Pascal ** definition (exponent)

Tags: operators, pascal, exponent

I was looking for the definition in Extended Pascal for the ** exponentiation operation. I've been looking for awhile now and can't seem to find it.

```
i.e 2**3 = 8
```

Comment: What do you mean by definition? It's called exponentiation and is probably implemented using the square-and-multiply approach or some variant of that.

Comment: Most Pascal implementations provide standard functions for Exp, Ln and Power.  For example: http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/math/power.html

Comment: I was looking for how Pascal implemented it

Comment: Free Pascal does not follow extended Pascal, we just borrowed the syntax when we implemented an exponentiation operator. The Pascal standards afaik still require a fee to obtain, though parts of them have been seen floating on the web (based on publicized bits or drafts?)

Comment: Compilers are free to implement language features however they like. There is no single definition of how "Pascal" implements the operator. Of which compiler were you looking for the operator's definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In FreePascal it is implemented in the math unit:

```
operator ** (bas,expo : float) e: float; inline;
  begin
    e:=power(bas,expo);
  end;


operator ** (bas,expo : int64) i: int64; inline;
  begin
    i:=round(intpower(bas,expo));
  end;

function power(base,exponent : float) : float;

  begin
    if Exponent=0.0 then
      result:=1.0
    else if (base=0.0) and (exponent>0.0) then
      result:=0.0
    else if (abs(exponent)<=maxint) and (frac(exponent)=0.0) then
      result:=intpower(base,trunc(exponent))
    else if base>0.0 then
      result:=exp(exponent * ln (base))
    else
      InvalidArgument;
  end;

function intpower(base : float;const exponent : Integer) : float;

  var
     i : longint;

  begin
     if (base = 0.0) and (exponent = 0) then
       result:=1
     else
       begin
         i:=abs(exponent);
         intpower:=1.0;
         while i>0 do
           begin
              while (i and 1)=0 do
                begin
                   i:=i shr 1;
                   base:=sqr(base);
                end;
              i:=i-1;
              intpower:=intpower*base;
           end;
         if exponent<0 then
           intpower:=1.0/intpower;
       end;
  end;
```